# MySQL UDF in C to return first non-empty value from list

Tags: c, mysql

I have a function that I wrote a while ago in PHP called `ifempty`, which I could pass an infinite(ish) amount of values and it would return the first one that wasn't purely white space or empty, like `ifempty('', null, '\n\n\n   \t', 'test')` would return `'test'`. That one works awesome.

But then I needed (really wanted) the same thing in MySQL, only to learn that MySQL functions can't have a dynamic amount of parameters, but UDFs written in C can. So I wrote this:

```
#ifdef STANDARD
/* STANDARD is defined, don't use any mysql functions */
#include <string.h>
#ifdef __WIN__
typedef unsigned __int64 ulonglong; /* Microsofts 64 bit types */
typedef __int64 longlong;
#else
typedef unsigned long long ulonglong;
typedef long long longlong;
#endif /*__WIN__*/
#else
#include <my_global.h>
#include <my_sys.h>
#if defined(MYSQL_SERVER)
#include <m_string.h>
#else
/* when compiled as standalone */
#include <string.h>
#endif
#endif
#include <mysql.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#ifdef HAVE_DLOPEN

char *trim(char *str) {
    size_t len = 0;
    char *frontp = str;
    char *endp = NULL;

    if (str == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    if (str[0] == '\0') {
        return str;
    }

    len = strlen(str);
    endp = str + len;

    /* Move the front and back pointers to address the first non-whitespace
     * characters from each end.
     */
    while (isspace((unsigned char) *frontp)) {
        ++frontp;
    }
    if (endp != frontp) {
        while (isspace((unsigned char) *(--endp)) && endp != frontp) {
        }
    }

    if (str + len - 1 != endp)
        *(endp + 1) = '\0';
    else if (frontp != str && endp == frontp)
        *str = '\0';

    /* Shift the string so that it starts at str so that if it's dynamically
     * allocated, we can still free it on the returned pointer.  Note the reuse
     * of endp to mean the front of the string buffer now.
     */
    endp = str;
    if (frontp != str) {
        while (*frontp) {
            *endp++ = *frontp++;
        }
        *endp = '\0';
    }


    return str;
}

my_bool ifempty_init(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args, char *message);
void ifempty_deinit(UDF_INIT *initid);
char* ifempty(UDF_INIT *initid __attribute__ ((unused)), UDF_ARGS *args, char *result, unsigned long *length, char *is_null, char *message __attribute__ ((unused)));

my_bool ifempty_init(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args, char *message) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < args->arg_count; i++) {
        args->arg_type[i] = STRING_RESULT;
    }

    initid->maybe_null = 1; //can return null

    return 0;
}

char* ifempty(UDF_INIT *initid __attribute__ ((unused)), UDF_ARGS *args, char *result, unsigned long *length, char *is_null, char *message __attribute__ ((unused))) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < args->arg_count; i++) {
        if (args->args[i] == NULL)
            continue;

        if (args->lengths[i] == 0)
            continue;

        if (strlen(trim(args->args[i])) == 0)
            continue;

        *length = args->lengths[i];
        return args->args[i];
    }

    *is_null = 1;
    return '\0';
}

#endif /* HAVE_DLOPEN */
```

Coming from PHP to C, I have to admit that memory management eludes me, so I was almost certain there were some issues here, but it seemed to be working. But now our MySQL server is getting a lot more usage, and we're getting some crashes every once in a while that are getting tracked down to this function.

Is there anything glaringly obvious that I missed? What would be some ways to clean up this code?

---

EDIT: This post wasn't actually about a program that wasn't working, I wrongly thought it was this, but it was definitely working as expected, but I thought to leave it here because it was my first production-used C program, and I definitely could use some pointers on efficiency.

Comment: "and we're getting some crashes every once in a while that are getting tracked down to this function." Code Review is not a debugging service, we review working code. How do you test your code and does it properly run through those test cases? Do your test cases contain enough iterations and have you profiled the program in action?

Comment: @Mast ah that would be totally my bad, I come from Stack Overflow, so I'm not perfectly up to date on the rules of this branch. It works most of the time, I've only seen it fail twice in the last few months though. It might even be linked to a MySQL bug itself, so I'm not sure the error is with my code at all

Comment: About the wording of your question (I thought it was broken, but I was wrong or whatever) you might be interested in reading https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8446/i-think-my-code-might-have-a-bug-but-i-am-not-sure-if-it-actually-does-is-it-b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your `trim` function, I see this:

```
while (isspace((unsigned char) *frontp)) {
    ++frontp;
}
```

You are not taking into consideration what would happen if the end of the string occurs. C strings are NUL-terminated, meaning they end when a "zero" byte is encountered. You want to do something like this:

```
while (*frontp && isspace(*frontp)) {
    ++frontp;
}

if (frontp == endp) { ... }
```

But really, you should not be writing this `trim` function at all. The point of your UDF, if I understood correctly, is to *evaluate* its arguments and return one of them unchanged.

So, just do that:

```
for (all those args) {
    if (str == NULL) // Can this happen? Is this check worthless?
        continue;

    register const char * startp;  // or whatever type MySQL wants

    for (startp = str; *startp && isspace(*startp); ++startp)
        /* empty */ ;

    if (*startp)    // (*startp != '\0') 
        return str; // Not at EOS? Winner, winner, chicken dinner!
}

// Didn't return? No values found. Return whatever 
return YOU_LOSE;
```

Also, be aware that the inner loop here is basically the `strcspn` library function, if you have a simple list of what matches `isspace()`. (That is, it would probably work for ASCII/LATIN1, but might not work for full Unicode.) So if you have a simple encoding on your DB, consider testing both this version (with `isspace`) and a version that uses `strcspn` to see which one is faster.

Comment: Your approach is fantastic (and thanks for answering, turns out it really wasn't my program having problems, so it was working as expected), but there is one issue with this and I can't spot why, but I get a ton (~700) of extra bytes returned when using this in MySQL

Comment: Never mind that, it was me being dumb :)

Comment: And oh my, (this is super insignificant in the cope it's being used in, but hey) your version does 10,000,000 calls in 44% of the time as my original